# How do I Stored Proc this data with SQL?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

```
if object_id('tempdb..#timing') is not null drop table #timing

create table #timing (
    logid int identity(1, 1),
    empid int,
    logtime datetime
)

insert into #timing
select 11, '20111201 8:03' union all select 11, '20111201 8:09' union all
select 12, '20111201 8:38' union all select 12, '20111201 9:31' union all
select 12, '20111201 9:31' union all select 12, '20111201 9:36' union all
select 11, '20111201 9:37' union all select 11, '20111201 9:44' union all
select 11, '20111201 9:48' union all select 11, '20111201 9:50'


;with cte as (
    select top 100 percent 
        empid,
        cast(datepart(hh, logtime) as varchar(2)) + ':' +
        right('0' + cast(datepart(mi, logtime) as varchar(2)), 2) as logtime,
        row_number() over (partition by empid order by logid) as row
    from #timing
    order by logid asc
)
select c1.empid as EmployeeID, min(c1.logtime) as InTime, max(c2.logtime) as OutTime, min(isnull(p.punches, '')) as Punches
from cte c1
join cte c2 on c1.row + 1 = c2.row and c1.empid = c2.empid
left join (
    select empid,
        (select '(' + stuff(
            (select ', ' +c1.logtime + ' In, ' + c2.logtime + ' Out'
            from cte c1
            join cte c2 on c1.row + 1 = c2.row and c1.empid = c2.empid
            where c1.row % 2 = 1 and c3.empid = c1.empid
            for xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]','varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') + ')'
        ) as punches
    from cte c3
    group by empid
) as p on p.empid = c1.empid
group by c1.empid
order by c1.empid
```

In this query i have used Logtime field type varchar as a string and Date field as a DateTime so help me for changes in this query.

this query is perfect but i have used logtime as varchar type.so i dont get perfect output in my report.

how can achieve it ?

Comment: What does your timing table look like?

Comment: My table data is like this:

    LogId      EmployeeId      LogTime                          Date

Comment: How do you determine which row to output "punches" to?

Comment: LogTime Row is determine punches time...

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** (after question clarification)

I would do it that way, example data:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#timing') is not null drop table #timing

create table #timing (
    logid int identity(1, 1),
    empid int,
    logtime datetime
)

insert into #timing
select 11, '20111201 8:03' union all select 11, '20111201 8:09' union all
select 12, '20111201 8:38' union all select 12, '20111201 9:31' union all
select 12, '20111201 9:31' union all select 12, '20111201 9:36' union all
select 11, '20111201 9:37' union all select 11, '20111201 9:44' union all
select 11, '20111201 9:48' union all select 11, '20111201 9:50'
```

and final query:

```
;with cte as (
    select
        empid,
        cast(datepart(hh, logtime) as varchar(2)) + ':' +
        right('0' + cast(datepart(mi, logtime) as varchar(2)), 2) as logtime,
        row_number() over (partition by empid order by logid) as row
    from #timing
)
select c1.empid as EmployeeID, c1.logtime as InTime, c2.logtime as OutTime, isnull(p.punches, '') as Punches
from cte c1
join cte c2 on c1.row + 1 = c2.row and c1.empid = c2.empid
left join (
    select empid,
        (select '(' + stuff(
            (select ', ' +c1.logtime + ' In, ' + c2.logtime + ' Out'
            from cte c1
            join cte c2 on c1.row + 1 = c2.row and c1.empid = c2.empid
            where c1.row % 2 = 1 and c3.empid = c1.empid
            for xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]','varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') + ')'
        ) as punches
    from cte c3
    group by empid
) as p on c2.row = (select max(row) from cte where empid = c2.empid) and p.empid = c2.empid
where c1.row % 2 = 1
order by c1.empid, c1.row
```

result:

```
EmployeeID  InTime  OutTime Punches
11          8:03    8:09    
11          9:37    9:44    
11          9:48    9:50    (8:03 In, 8:09 Out, 9:37 In, 9:44 Out, 9:48 In, 9:50 Out)
12          8:38    9:31    
12          9:31    9:36    (8:38 In, 9:31 Out, 9:31 In, 9:36 Out)
```

**Added:**

Another report:

```
;with cte as (
    select
        empid,
        cast(datepart(hh, logtime) as varchar(2)) + ':' +
        right('0' + cast(datepart(mi, logtime) as varchar(2)), 2) as logtime,
        row_number() over (partition by empid order by logid) as row
    from #timing
)
select c1.empid as EmployeeID, min(c1.logtime) as InTime, max(c2.logtime) as OutTime, min(isnull(p.punches, '')) as Punches
from cte c1
join cte c2 on c1.row + 1 = c2.row and c1.empid = c2.empid
left join (
    select empid,
        (select '(' + stuff(
            (select ', ' +c1.logtime + ' In, ' + c2.logtime + ' Out'
            from cte c1
            join cte c2 on c1.row + 1 = c2.row and c1.empid = c2.empid
            where c1.row % 2 = 1 and c3.empid = c1.empid
            for xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]','varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') + ')'
        ) as punches
    from cte c3
    group by empid
) as p on p.empid = c1.empid
group by c1.empid
order by c1.empid
```

Please bear in mind that result is for mine sample data:

```
EmployeeID  InTime  OutTime Punches
11          8:03    9:50    (8:03 In, 8:09 Out, 9:37 In, 9:44 Out, 9:48 In, 9:50 Out)
12          8:38    9:36    (8:38 In, 9:31 Out, 9:31 In, 9:36 Out)
```

Comment: how can i add EmployeeID in this query i want add employeeId also.

Comment: @user1070790 added query for your another report.

Comment: Plz check my edit.i need some help in this query...@Michal Powaga

Comment: how can i use this query into stored procedure ?

Comment: @user1070790, which one, the first or the second query? Does your procedure has parameters (if yes, then what)? What is the name of SP?

Comment: ,Second one query and my procedure has no parameters..SP name is spReportPunchRecord.